# php too slow on linux?

Tags: php, linux, windows

My php on linux server is too slow, but faster on my 127.0.0.1 (windows local host). any ideas to improve speed on linux server?
I'm doing file reading, file writing processes in my php code.

Comment: The linux machine is remote? Define "Slow". Keep in mind that if you have a remote machine, the php processing time isn't the same as the time you need to see the results. For example a php script can take 0.005 seconds to perform an action, and due to your internet connection speed and other factors, see the result like at 1 second. Try using microtime() and loop a function for 1000 times to test the real php processing speed on both servers

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP to EasyPHP MySQL server 1 second connection delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310564/php-to-easyphp-mysql-server-1-second-connection-delay)

Comment: you mean your online (hosting) linux server is slow ?

Comment: Please provide more information. What parts of it is slow? What code are you using? Is it just your network connection accessing the server or is it the actual server processing? Is it shared hosting ? Is it a dedicated server? what is the spec of the hosting.  We need much more information to provide answers.

Comment: @aleation,@NullPonyPointer : yes, it's damn slow, it's online (hosting) linux server.

Comment: @sri than talk to hosting providers about it ans make sure you are not running query in loop

Comment: Try running something like this and tell us the echo on both of your servers...
`$start = microtime(true);

 $counter = 0;
 for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
  $counter += $i;
 }

 echo microtime(true) - $start;`

Comment: localhost tends to be faster then remote, that's the nature of the internet. You really have to define slow, "damn slow" isn't good enough, it's not measurable. Like others have suggested time how long your PHP takes to execute in both environments so you can narrow it down.

Comment: @aleation 0.91329503059387 On windows, 0.903809070587 on linux hosting server.

Comment: then php is not slower on linux hosting, they are the same, 0.01 difference is nothing. It´s the network/connection speed. try to ping your server and see the delay in ms you have. Also go to any speed test site to see your normal ping, this way you can determine if it´s your connection speed fault or it´s the server´s

Comment: ok friends, thanks for all ur valuable answers and quick responses.

Answer (score 3):

it isn't too slow use `127.0.0.1` instead `Localhost`

its because when we use hostname (like localhost ) the mysql client  first tries this with ipv6 host name and if it failed than it fallback with ipv4

Comment: i'm using 127.0.0.1 only as "define("DBHOST","127.0.0.1");" . is it ok ? or i need to change?