# One second delay on EasyPHP - IPV4 vs IPV6

Tags: easyphp

Some months ago I got this computer and while running EasyPHP I perceived a 1 second delay to page load that didn't happen on my previous PC. I searched for some help and resolved it. The problem is that I've formated the PC now and I don't remember how I did that.

I kinda remember it was about changing something about ServerName in httpd.conf file, but I don't know what. I also found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436435/4501021. Ok, I think that is the problem, but I have no idea on how to solve. The answer talk about some issues but WHERE do I need to change it? I'm newbie, I know nothing about it, so, if a good man come and tell me exactly what files I need to change that would be lovely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've earned the tumbleweed badge from this question o/

I HAVE THE ANSWEAR GUYS

Open the following folder

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Now, open the notepad as admin and load the file "hosts" and remove the comment from this line:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

That's all folks, at least I think it is. Be happy.